# Proper way to use memcpy for copying vector data to wstring

Tags: c++, memcpy, wstring

I have a raw data :
`47 00 61 00 6D 00 65 00 41 00 73 00 73 00 65 00 74 00` = G.a.m.e.A.s.s.e.t.
and it's stored at position 15 in a `vector<char>` array.

Now I want to copy it to a **wstring** value but I get '3221225477' error code.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
wstring                             string_Data;
std::memcpy(&string_Data, &file_buffer.data()[15], 18);
```

it's working on all of my other values , just wstring doesn't work.

If I use `wcout << string_Data << endl;` it doesn't crash but prints value with 3 of ? , It shows `GameAsset???` in console.

And if I use `wcout << string_Data.c_str() << endl;` it will crash.

What am I doing wrong ? what is the proper way of doing this by using **memcpy** ???

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Why do you have to copy the data into a wstring to being with? If you need the string in the form of a string, then why is it in a vector in the first place?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Good question! it's because I made a custom binary file with my own serialization and in deserializer , I decompressed using zlib to a vector of chars , then read the binary data to its values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::wstring` holds a pointer to character data that is stored elsewhere in memory. But you are not allocating that memory for it to point at, to copy your character data into. You are copying the character data directly onto the `wstring` itself, corrupting its internals, and likely surrounding memory.

Try this instead:

```cpp
wstring string_Data;
string_Data.resize(9);
std::memcpy(&string_Data[0], file_buffer.data()+15, 18);
// or:
// std::copy(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(file_buffer.data()+15), reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(file_buffer.data()+33), string_Data.begin());
```

Alternatively, you can use the `std::wstring::assign()` method:

```cpp
wstring string_Data;
string_Data.assign(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(file_buffer.data()+15), 9);
```

Or the `std::wstring` constructor:

```cpp
wstring string_Data(reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(file_buffer.data()+15), 9);
```

Either way, just note that `wchar_t` is not very portable. It is 16bit only on Windows, where `wchar_t` is handled using UTF-16. If you need this code to work on other platforms, where `wchar_t` is handled using UTF-32 instead, then you should interpret the `vector` data using `char16_t` and copy it into a`std::u16string`, or convert it to `std::wstring` using `std::wstring_convert` or any Unicode library of your choosing (ICU, etc).

Comment: Thanks Remy it's a very well explained answer , but I couldn't make your code work , I get `argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *"` error at memcpy using `string_Data.data()` ... did you forget something?

Comment: I know it can be fixed by using `(void*)string_Data.data()` and it works but why you didn't use it in your code ?

Comment: @J.Mcgill my bad, I keep forgetting that a **non-const** `data()` wasn't added until C++17. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! just adding , std::wmemcpy can get the job done too!